# NodeJS leaking socket file descriptors

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a running NodeJS script that is not closing socket file descriptors. Here's an oversimplified version of the code I'm using:

```
const socketServer = createServer(socket => {
  socket.on("close", () => {
    socket.destroy()
    console.log("Socket destroyed")
  })
  socket.on("data", () => {
    // do whatever needs to be done
    socket.end("blah blah")
  })
})

socketServer.listen(5000)
```

If I run the server and let it do its thing, the file descriptors start to add up:
`ll /proc/{pid}/fd | wc -l`

The client is a Java tomcat application that will poll this server once in a while, open a socket and close. I see this happen, as "Socket closed" is printed to stdout (eventually to a PM2 log), but the file descriptors still remain.

I'm using Node `6.14.1`

Any ideas on why this is happening?